# How to enable Unattended Access in anydesk, debian 10, openbox, lightdm

Tags: debian, remote-desktop

Regarding
https://support.anydesk.com/Command_Line_Interface#Setting_a_Password

I login

```bsh
$ su -
```

and do

```bsh
# echo my_new_password | anydesk.exe --set-password
```

after that I exit/login to standard user and start

```bsh
$ anydesk
```

But I still need client accepts (now password request from remote)

Answer (score 4):

I think you should remove .exe and use sudo (tested at least on ubuntu 20.04)

```
# echo my-new-password | sudo anydesk --set-password
```

Comment: if you are running as root, you don't need sudo. Although tbh probably better to use sudo than to run as root

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason is that the password is too weak. In this case, AnyDesk rejects your password without prompting any warning. So the password is still not set, therefore the unattended access is still disabled.